# Plotting tuples from for loop using zip() in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, zip, histogram

I have two sets of numbers (they're really dictionaries), `a` and `b`. There are two types of numbers in there that I want to plot. Specifically, for each number in `a` there is a corresponding number in `b`, and I want the numbers in `a` that are equal to one another and sum the numbers in `b` for that number. For example:

The number `310` occurs many times in `a`,  so I want to sum all the numbers in `b` that corresponds to `310`.

> ```
> for i, j in zip(a, b):
>         print(i["number1"], j["number2"])
> ```

This code gives me all the tuples, but for all equal numbers of `i["number1"]` I need to sum the corresponding `j["number2"]`. In the end I want to plot this in a histogram, so I need one array or list of tuples: `[(310, sum of numbers in b for 310),(420, ... for 420), ...]`, and I'm not quite sure how to append those tuples into one array that I can plot.

Comment: create a new list and compare the sum if condition satisfies add the elements to list

Comment: What are the `type`s of `a` and `b`? It can't be a `set` because sets don't allow duplicates? Perhaps you can share fragments of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Ronald I know it's not a set in a mathematical sense, I was using the concept of collection. `a` is a Series and `b` is a dictionary. The types of `i["numbers"]` and `j["numbers"]` have the types of `float` and `int`, respectively. 

That is, in practice `i["number1"]` should just be `i` because `a` isn't really a dictionary. I just tried to not complicate things by making everything the same in the post.

So, `print(i["number1"], j["number2"])` yields:
            
        `310.0   1322
        510.0   678
        420.0   1203
        310.0   2347`
        .
        .
        .

Comment: I already thought something like that. Please share both lists (or a sufficiently large fragement), then I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Or does this answer your question already:

```
a = [310.0, 510.0, 420.0, 310.0]
b = [1322, 678, 1203, 2347]

print(sum([j for i, j in zip(a,b) if i==310.0]))
>>> 3669
```